# Remove all QT packages using Pacman

Tags: msys2, pacman

I want to remove QT5 and QT6 from my MSYS install. MSYS uses Pacman as its package manager.

Luckily, the packages I want to remove all follow a pattern in their name:

`mingw-w64-x86_86-qt5-*`

However, I cannot figure out how to remove them all. Trying with -R (remove) -s (search) finds all of them, but complains about the dependencies.

Once all of them are removed, there will be no dependency problem - nothing else relies on them but each other.

Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: Whoops, I've been using both recently and mis-tagged.

Comment: Perfect, I removed my comments.